# Prove that $f$ is bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ is a the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear map such that:
>
> $ \begin{cases} 
> f(e_1) = \frac{1}{3}(-e_1 + 2e_2 + 2e_3) \\
> f(e_2) = \frac{1}{3}(2e_1 - e_2 + 2e_3) \\
> f(e_3) = \frac{1}{3}(2e_1 + 2e_2 - e_3)
> \end{cases} $
>
> We have: $E_{-1} = \{ u \in \mathbb{R}^3 | f(u) = -u\}$ and $E_{1} = \{ u \in \mathbb{R}^3 | f(u) = u\}$
>
> 1. Prove that $E_{-1}$ and $E_{1}$ are sub-vector spaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
> 2. Prove that $e_1 - e_2 \in E_{-1}$ and $e_1 - e_3 \in E_{-1} $ and $e_1 + e_2 
>     + e_3 \in E_{1}$.
> 3. What can we deduce about the dimensions of $E_{-1}$ and $E_{1}$?
> 4. Determine $E_{-1} \cap E_{1}$.
> 5. Do we have $E_{-1} \oplus E_{1} = \mathbb{R}^3 $ ?
> 6. Compute $f^2 = f \circ f$, deduce that $f$ is bijective and determine $f^{-1}$.

---

I am stuck in question 3. I don't know how to deduce the dimensions of $E_{-1}$ and $E_{1}$ from $e_1 - e_2 \in E_{-1}$ and $e_1 - e_3 \in E_{-1} $ and $e_1 + e_2 + e_3 \in E_{1}$.

I have problem with question 6 too, I have written the matrix $A$ of the linear map which is:

$A = \frac{1}{3}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

and $A^2 = I_3$

Which means $A^{-1} = A$.

and $f^{-1}(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{9}(-x + 2y + 2z , 2x - y + 2z , 2x + 2y - y)$

How can I deduce $f$ is bijective from $f^2$ ?

Although, is $f^{-1}$ correct?

Comment: For 3, notice that $e_1-e_2$, $e_1-e_3$, and $e_1+e_2+e_3$ are linearly independent. For 4, think about the following: if $f$ is not bijective, can $f^2$ be?

Comment: The vectors are linearly independent means, means $dimE_{-1} \geq 2$ and $dimE_1 \leq 1$. Since $\dim \mathbb{R}^3 = 3$. Can we say $dimE_{-1} = 2 $ and $ dimE_1 = 1 $ ? 

For the question 6. I don't know how to use your hint. I have $f^2 = Id$, how can I get the bijectivity from this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $E_{-1}$ contains two linearly independent vectors, certainly $\dim E_{-1}\ge 2$. Likewise, $\dim E_1\ge 1$. With the answer to 4., yoiu dhould be able to deduce that $\dim E_{-1}+\dim E_1\le 3$. This then implies $\dim E_{-1}=2$ and $\dim E_1=1$.

For question 6, you better do not express $A$ in terms of the standard basis - that leads to clumsy computations with awfully many numbers. Instead, what is $f(f(u))$ for $u\in E_{-1}$? What is $f(f(u))$ for $u\in E_1$ (both by the very definition of $E_{\pm1}$ as set)= What does this tell you about $f\circ f$?

Comment: For question 6, $f^{2}(u) = u$ for $u \in E_{-1} \cup E_{1}$. This tells me about $f \circ f = Id$. I don't see how to get the bijectivity from this.

Comment: How can I proceed?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi recall that $f \circ g = Id$ implies that $g$ is injective and $f$ is surjective. You have shown that $f \circ f$ is the identity, so...?

Comment: @Student I did not know this result. I need to prove it, though. It answers my question, thank you so much. I have one more question please. Is it possible to prove the bijectivity of $f$ using the rank-nulity theorem? Thank you so much.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi: yes: the rank of the matrix is 3, hence the null space is trivial. This proves that the map is injective (trivial kernel) and surjective (image is a three dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$